# Zoom in on small photos without losing pixel crispness

Tags: image-viewers, eog

I'm working on some pixel art but when I preview it in something like eye of gnome, the image gets blurry instead of showing crisp pixels. I know this sounds backwards, but how do I prevent that?

Opening the file in GIMP shows crisp pixels as expected but GIMP is really big to just view photos quickly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Silly me; there's an option in eog for smoothing images when zoomed in and out...

[image: Settings Screenshot]

I guess this just goes to show that over thinking something makes you look stupid when you fail to find the obvious...
However, I'll leave the question here so others can benefit if they made the same blunder I did.

Comment: I wish I could either make this option the default so when I launch eog from a terminal it would render using this option

Comment: @ScottStensland Or a command line option!